# SQL PIVOT Query, column based on value

Tags: sql

I'm stuck and do not seem to find the right foo for searching on Google for the answer.

What I'm trying to do is to get the value from a column, the column is based on the value from another column:

I have two tables:

```
pID | name | period
 0    abc      1
 1    def      2
 2    ghi      3
```

and

```
pID | p1 | p2 | p3
 0    10   20   30
 1    40   50   60
 2    70   80   90
```

I'd like to do a query that displays all pID's, their name, period and what value that period has. The output should be:

```
pID | name | period | NewVal
 0    abc      1        10
 1    def      2        50
 2    ghi      3        90
```

I hope it is clear what I'm trying to do!

Thanks * 1000

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Are the values in 3rd column (Period) of table 1 fixed i.e. do you know the range of values it has? Also, are the number of columns P1, P2 ,P3 in table 2 are also fixed? Or this is something dynamically generated depending upon the number of periods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if the number of periods is fixed, then you can try to use `CASE`:

```
select t1.pID, t1.name, t1.period,
 CASE t1.period
  WHEN 1 THEN t2.p1 
  WHEN 2 THEN t2.p2
  WHEN 3 THEN t2.p3
 END as NewVal
from t1
inner join t2 on t2.pID = t1.pID;
```

Answer (score 0):

For *statically defined columns* you can use a query like the following:

```
SELECT t1.pID, t1.name, t1.period,
       CASE t1.period
          WHEN 1 THEN t2.p1 
          WHEN 2 THEN t2.p2
          WHEN 3 THEN t2.p3
       END AS NewVal
FROM Table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t1.pID = t2.PID
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e92cc3/2)